# Nested xy-pic diagrams

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

Is it possible to include a `xy-pic` diagram as an entry of another `xy-pic` diagram? I have a map to a group of homomorphisms and I would like to print the homomorphism image. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible like that, I.e. you can't use `\xymatrix` inside a `\xymatrix`.

But the macros `\save` and `\restore` may be of some help. See p.11 of the [xyguide](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf).